# Does an Android Wear device need to wake wifi?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android wear app with a foreground service that runs constantly. At some point the app may need to send a brief message over wifi when an event happens. My question is - do I need to wake up the wifi radio, or will Android automatically do that when I use something like HttpURLConnection to send a REST request?

The Android SDK docs mention wifiLock as a way to keep the radio on, but in my case I'm not trying to keep it on.